# check allowed file type while uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't want force my web admin to upload image while adding product through dashboard, but if he/she uploads then i want to check for the allowed file type and if not allowed i want to throw error message in codeigniter.
here is what i did according to user guide of codeigniter:

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './content/uploads/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000';
        $config['max_width'] = '2000';
        $config['max_height'] = '2000';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pName', 'Name', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[200]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pPrice', 'Price', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[200]');
         if (($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) || (!$this->upload->do_upload())) {

            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            $this->load->view('product/addProduct', $data);
        } else {


            //if valid
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('myfile')) {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('myfile'));
                $productImg = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
```

but this method forces me to upload image, which i want optional. So is there any method/function or way to check is the file uploaded is of allowed format on upload and leave unchecked if not uploaded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to remove  $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors(); or check if file uploaded then use it in form validation run block

Comment: im not sure there is a way to do this within the CI input class. What you need to do is check if the file has been uploaded and if so run the `do_upload` method. This can be done by checking the $_FILES superglobal var. Checkout http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php for more information about the $FILES superglobal

Comment: Thank you @ Rakesh and @mic for your answer and now my problem is solved by checking file type in one function and calling that function on set rule.